# Django filter get latest records of each employee

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter

I have a table named employee

Employee

```
empid  name   status      created_datetime
EMP001 NAMEA  STATUS-B    2022-06-13 14:00:00
EMP001 NAMEA  STATUS-A    2022-06-13 13:00:00
EMP002 NAMEB  STATUS-B    2022-06-13 12:00:00
EMP003 NAMEC  STATUS-A    2022-06-13 11:30:00
EMP001 NAMEA  STATUS-C    2022-06-13 11:00:00
EMP001 NAMEA  STATUS-D    2022-06-13 10:00:00
EMP003 NAMEC  STATUS-B    2022-06-13 09:00:00
```

What i need to fetch is that the latest records of each employee.
For example

```
empid  name   status      created_datetime
EMP001 NAMEA  STATUS-B    2022-06-13 14:00:00
EMP002 NAMEB  STATUS-B    2022-06-13 12:00:00
EMP003 NAMEC  STATUS-A    2022-06-13 11:30:00
```

these are the latest records of the employee EMP001,EM002 and EMP003

Comment: Can you share your `Employee` model?

Comment: @SunderamDubey the problem is that there is no employee model.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: its just creating the records without any foreign key relationships.

Comment: would you please share the views.py code from where you're fetching the records?